# Should you use a comma with "single unified"?

Tags: adjectives, commas

Should you use a comma in the term "single unified"? Here are two examples. (I have kept the original punctuation.)

> The company uses a single, unified database for all its customer information.
>
> The company is a pioneer in using a single unified and companywide platform.

I have read mixed assessments of whether a comma is needed.

Comment: `Needed` is a strong word, a comma certainly seems preferable to me.

Comment: The big, black dog.  That said, if it is single, why say unified?Sounds "furrin". How could it be unified if there were two databases??

Comment: @Lambie I agree but "single unified" seems to be a common expression, well accepted, especially in technology writing.

Comment: Are you interested in common expressions?  Or good English? https://www.simeiosolutions.com/we-provide-a-single-unified-interface/

Comment: I doubt that it's bad English to say "single, unified" when referring to a "single" entity that literally "unifies" multiple things that were once, or recently, separate.

Comment: Single, unified x is like big, bad wolf. There is no reason not to use a comma.  But it also somewhat pleonastic. The bad English I was referring to was the absence of a comma ....a single database (as in an Oracle database) cannot be anything but unified, if it is single.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Use of comma separating two adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/54452/14666), [Commas for multiple adjectives](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/365473/14666)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it would seem the comma is needed. This is the very [distinction](https://www.englishgrammar101.com/module-5/modifiers-adjectives-and-adverbs/lesson-4/order-of-adjectives) between **coordinate** and **cumulative** adjectives.

If two modifiers are describing the same feature (and would make sense with the word "and" between them) they are **coordinate**. The "and" should then be replaced with a comma. As long as the cumulative adjective isn't used to create a compound noun, the comma is needed.

Example: 
*The wealthy, elegant lady looks like a model.*

In contrast, **cumulative** adjectives build upon each other and must be in a certain order. They don't take "and" or commas between them.

Example:
*The big old black bull followed the young Brahma cow.*

In OP's example, since single and unified are both modifying "database" in the same way (number/size), they are **coordinate** adjectives. The sentence would read correctly if written:

> The company uses a single *and* unified database for all its customer
>   information.

Therefore we can replace the "and" with a comma:

> The company uses a single, unified database for all its customer
>   information.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what the noun is. If the writer is talking about *database* as the noun, you need a comma (single, unified database). By contrast, if the writer is talking about *unified database* as the compound noun, then the adjective *single* modifies *unified database*, so no comma there.

Comment: While that's true, the question seems to be about whether the  two modifiers need necessarily be separated by a comma when they both modify the noun.

Comment: Yes, if the two modifiers can be separated using "and" and still the intended meaning is conveyed, I will use a comma between them.

Comment: *"if the two modifiers can be separated using "and" and still the intended meaning is conveyed, I will use a comma between them"* __ that is indeed the right logic @Arun, which you can edit into your answer. You can also strengthen your answer by adding an extract from (and link to) a standard online resource that mentions this approach or rule for using commas with adjectives.